# Do i need viewstate for input controls like checkbox, textbox etc?

Tags: asp.net

When `EnableViewstate = false` and I do postback, my textbox control retains the text value but label control does not. I am changing the text for both label and textbox on a button's click event.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = "Message Changed";
    Label1.Text = "Message Changed";
}
```

There is another button my page for just postback.

Also if I do no need viewstate for this control, then is there a list of all the controls that don't need the viewstate?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All controls which implement [`IPostBackDataHandler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.ipostbackdatahandler.aspx) load their values even if ViewState is off. Note that events like `TextChanged`  and other properties like `ForeColor` don't work when ViewState is disabled.

Here's a list of controls which implement `IPostBackDataHandler`

- CheckBox
- CheckBoxList
- DropDownList
- HtmlInputCheckBox
- HtmlInputFile
- HtmlInputHidden
- HtmlInputImage
- HtmlInputRadioButton
- HtmlInputText
- HtmlSelect
- HtmlTextArea
- ImageButton
- ListBox
- RadioButtonList
- TextBox

[Why textbox persists data during postback even if View State set to off](http://brijbhushan.net/2011/02/07/why-textbox-persists-data-during-postback-even-if-view-state-set-to-off/)

> Whenever a page is submitted or posted back to server, the entire form
>   data is posted to the server as a collection with the request. The
>   collection is in the form of NamedValue collection and this collection
>   has the mapping with uniqueid of the control and the value of the
>   control. You can read the data from the form collection by using the
>   following code snippet

```
//Reading textbox value from the form collection 
string textboxvalue = Request.Form[textbox1.UniqueID];
```

> ASP.NET uses this primitive to update the control’s value. ASP.NET
>   uses IPostBackDataHandler  for the controls that load the data from
>   the form collection.

Comment: Tim, you are a god.  I bet you knew that off the top of your head, right?  Ahhh the horrors of ASP.NET sausage making...

Comment: Thanks Tim. Your answer helped. However another question comes to my mind with this. Why can't i find Request.Form[Label1.UniqueID] in the posback? Label is also the part of form data right? Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: @UditGupta No, the `Label` is rendered as a `<span>`, which does not post back to the server in a form.

Answer (score 2):

`ViewState` is a messy hack to persist data between requests. The web is stateless and `ViewState` tries to make it appear stateful.

I believe the `TextBox` (and other `<input/>` controls) keep their value without `ViewState` because their values are POSTed in a form, while `Label` (`<span/>`) values are not. See @Tim Schmelter's answer for more on this.

Many Web Forms developers that care about page size will disable `ViewState` globally and only enable it for specific controls. If you use standard paging in a `GridView`, for example, you will need `ViewState` so that ASP.NET knows what page number the user clicked. You could use custom paging and use actual links for the page numbers and then turn on off `ViewState`.

It's an interesting task to use Web Forms without `ViewState` as you lose a lot of the easy to use features of server controls but gain much more in control of your markup and state. However, it's my opinion that if you want that much control, you should consider using MVC instead of Web Forms.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement. ViewState is used to preserve data during multiple postbacks of the page. If viewstate is enabled the data is preserved otherwise it is lost. As you mentioned the TextBox retains the data, I think the Browser also stores the textbox value in their Cache.